# Android: Layout. EditText Scrolls?

Tags: android, layout

this is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1fed7b">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="114"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_headline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="281"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="547"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_subline1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="106"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
   HERE!!!     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_hours" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="55sp" />
    HERE!!!    <TextView
            android:text=" : " 
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/txt_colon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="55sp" />
HERE!!        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/txt_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="55sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="189"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="118"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="140"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="hh"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/txt_hh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="110"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="140"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="mm"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/txt_mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="118"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="240"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="209"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is basically a timer with hours, a ":" and then minutes. For some reason though, the edittext both, when the app launches, are all the way at the top of the layout, only halfway visible. I need to scroll the 00 down to have them on the same hight as the colon.

a.) why can I scroll those? I dont want to scroll them!
b.) Even if they are scrollable (which I assume I can disable...) why are they always so far up, that they overlap half the layout and therfore are only halfway visible?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: are you using this layout in some other layout or this is your main layout file ?

Comment: this is the second to parent. the root layout is one out of 6 linearlayouts.

Comment: post your complete layout here.

Comment: edited the questions. its about the "here" part ;)

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: check my answer and tell me if it helped you or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this it will help you. I have checked it on multiple screen it's working fine on all of them:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="114"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_barcode2" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="281"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="44"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="547"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cart" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="44"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="106"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="00"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"

    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="55sp" />
   <TextView
    android:text=" : "
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/txt_colon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="55sp" />
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="00"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="55sp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="189"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="118"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="140"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="hh"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/txt_hh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="110"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="140"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="mm"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/txt_mm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="118"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="240"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="209"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Hope it helps you resolving your problem.

Comment: give me a minute :)

Comment: whopps something went wrong, the part on top is missing.

Comment: Then I believe you are adding this layout to some other layout. Otherwise it shows perfectly what you asked for

Comment: no, i ment your answer. there is a bit missing in the code it starts with: "    android:textColor="#ffffff"" which cannot be the case ;)

Comment: @innomotionmedia sorry i have updated the answer check now... :) and don't forget to change imagebutton src

Comment: tell me though, why was i able to scroll it earlier?

Comment: Glad I could be of help please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you

Comment: i did, but my reputation wont allw me to upvote it yet -.-

Comment: @innomotion you were messing with the heights in the layout. It was 0dp but should have been wrap_content and also the heights of edittexts.

Comment: THANKS! And the best thing: i am now able to vote for your answer. thanks a million!

Comment: I am glad that i could be of your help ... :)